# Slider alignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, slider, pyqt5

I have problems aligning the Slider Widget in a Box Layout. I want to align it in the horizontal center, but it always remains on the left.

```
self.btnPerson = QPushButton("Person", self)
self.btnPerson.setAutoDefault(False)
self.btnPerson.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(189,255,189)")
self.editor = QTextEdit(self)
self.slider = QSlider(self)

vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(self.btnPerson)
vbox.addWidget(self.editor)
vbox.addWidget(self.slider,QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
self.setLayout(vbox)

self.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because python take parameter depends on order as default so I think the Align Center pass to stretch parameter so try this:

```
vbox.addWidget(self.slider,alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
```